# Encoding-aware RandomAccessReader implementation?

Tags: java, character-encoding

The default implementation of RandomAccessFile is 'broken', in the sense that you can't specify which encoding your file is in.

I'm looking for an alternative which matches the following criteria:

1. Encoding-aware
2. Random access! (dealing with very big files, need to be able to position the cursor using a byte offset without streaming the whole thing).

I had a poke around in Commons IO, but there's nothing there. I'd rather not have to implement this myself, because there are entirely too many places it could go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

RandomAccessFile is intended for accessing binary data.  It is not possible to efficiently create a random access encoded file which is appropriate in all situations.

Even if you find such a solution I would check it carefully to ensure it suits your needs.

If you were to write it, I would suggest considering a random position of row and column rather than character offset from the start of the file.

This has the advantage that you only have to remember where the start of each line is and you can scan the line to get your character.  If you index the position of every character, this could use 4 bytes for every character (assuming the file is < 4 GB)

Comment: I'm aware of that, and I'm not looking for something that's appropriate in all situations. I just need a file input stream that's random access, so that I can position the cursor and then have an InputStreamReader take care of the encoding. The offset needs to be a byte offset, not a character offset. As far as I'm concerned, the file could contain megabytes worth of binary data, followed by character data.

Comment: How do you want to position the cursor, from the start of the file or by row/column?

Comment: If you just need byte offset, I would use RandomAccessFile, extract the bytes you want to turn into a String and use the String constructor to convert them.

Comment: That was my first attempt, but the string could potentially be gigabytes large, which is a bit painful :-). I know the offset and the length, but I have to be able to read line-by-line lest the whole thing run out of memory. I'm having a look at the RandomAccessFile->Channel->InputStream approach. If I can find a way to extract the (byte) position of the last read character then I'll be done :-) Thx

Comment: You only need to grab as many characters as you can display. i.e. 100-200 BTW: a 2 GB text files doesn't have to have more than one line.

Comment: I know, that's a separate use case entirely ;-)

Comment: I still suggest you grab the bytes you want to convert, as many as you want to and no more, and convert those bytes with `new String(bytes, charSet);`

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be less painful than I assumed:

```
// This gives me access to buffering and charset magic
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Channels.newInputStream(randomAccessFile.getChannel()), encoding)), encoding
....
```

I can then implement a readLine() method which reads *character by character*. Using String.getBytes(encoding) I can keep track of the offset in the file. Calling seek() on the underlying RandomAccessFile allows me to reposition the cursor at will. There are probably some bugs lurking in there, but the basic tests seem to work.

```
public String readLine() throws IOException {
    eol = "";
    lastLineByteCount = 0;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    char[] characters = new char[1];
    int status = reader.read(characters, 0, 1);

    if (status == -1) {
        return null;
    }

    char c = characters[0];
    while (status != -1) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            eol += c;
            break;
        }

        if (c == '\r') {
            eol += c;
        } else {
            builder.append(c);
        }

        status = reader.read(characters, 0, 1);
        c = characters[0];
    }

    String line = builder.toString();

    lastLineByteCount = line.getBytes(encoding).length + eol.getBytes(encoding).length;

    return line;
}
```